# What's the main cause of htmlentities exception in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder

Everybody I'm new here and working with Laravel for a while. I'm not so familiar with Laravel but keeping practicing and going ahead to overcome on my weaknesses,anyway today I'm facing with new error saying

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

How to solve it. 
This is my code in the controller:

```
$items = DB::table('items')
->join('currencies', 'currencies.cur_id', '=', 'items.currency_id')
->selectRaw('items.*, currencies.currency ,SUM(items.quantity*unit_price) as total,         SUM(items.c_price*quantity) as usd_total')
->first();
```

And the blade view

```
{{ $items->usd_total }}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: what are you sending to the view in your controller?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I send this return view('index', compact('items'));

Comment: Where is the $purchase object coming from if it isn't pass to the view through the controller? Might help to `dd($purchase);` to see what the attributes are and what `usd_total` is.

Comment: ooh, sorry I was changed it to {{ $items->usd_total }} , When I dd($items)  get this:    {#111 ▼
 +"id": 1
 +"item_name": "Muscle"
+"quantity": 12
+"unit_price": "100.0000"
+"c_price": "1.4440"
+"description": ""
+"buy_date": "2016-06-12"
+"purchase_type_id": 1
+"unit_id": 1
+"currency_id": 2
+"rate_id": 4
 +"brand_id": 1
 +"category_id": 1
+"created_at": "2016-06-12 22:35:10"
 +"updated_at": "2016-06-12 22:35:10"
+"currency": "AFN"
+"total": "28900.0000"
+"usd_total": "417.3280"
}

Comment: That is odd it is giving you that issue i have `{{ $mission->name }}` in my project and I do not get the issue you have. Maybe you have `{{ }}` somewhere in the view where you are just passing the `$items` object.

Comment: Yeah, your right Andrew Nolan . thank you